# Hide functions and global variables in the header file

Tags: c, header

I created a program in C that can find the determinant of a matrix

```
void fun1(); /*regardless of parameters they take*/
void fun2();
void fun3();
void fun4();
void fun5();

int global_var1; /*they are used among the above functions*/
int global_var2;
int global_var3;
int determinant;

int main(void){

int x,y;

for(x=0; x<something ; x++){
    for (y=0 ; y<another_thing; y++){
        fun1();
        fun2();
        fun3();
    }
 fun4();
 fun5();
}

printf("Determinant is: %d\n", determinant);

return 0;
}

void fun1(){/*code goes here to process the matrix*/;} 
void fun2(){/*code goes here to process the matrix*/;} 
void fun3(){/*code goes here to process the matrix*/;} 
void fun4(){/*code goes here to process the matrix*/;} 
void fun5(){/*code goes here to process the matrix*/;}
```

Now I need to use this program to find the determinant of a given matrix in another project.
I created a header file, named it `"matrix.h"` and I replaced the `int main(void)` with `int find_determinant()` to be used in the new project.

the prototype of the second program:

```
#include "matrix.h"

int main(void){
find_determinant(); /*regardless of para it takes, it works perfectly*/
return 0;}
```

it works properly, nothing wrong with it, but the only problem that if I want to give this header file `"matrix.h` to someone to use it in his program, he can know the signature of other functions (useless for him alone and confusing) that were used to help in finding the determinant in `int find_determinant()`.

My question is:
How can I hide (make them inaccessible) those functions and global variables and show only the `int find_determinant()` function in the second C file/program that contains `#include "matrix.h"` ?

Comment: 1. Don't put the stuff that's only used internally in the header.  2. Global vars and functions that don't need to be accessed by the user (are only used internally) should be marked `static`.  3. Global vars that *do* need to be accessed externally should be declared with `extern` in the header, and defined in the `.c` file.  4. You shouldn't use so many globals, and should have the functions pass the data they need via function arguments and return values.

Comment: A [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434971/how-to-hide-a-global-variable-which-is-visible-across-multiple-files) but I am sure I have seen more relevant. Provide functions to access what you want to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can put executable code in a header file, a good practice is to have your header file only contain declarations (for global variables) definitions and function prototypes. If you don't want to give your source code implementation, then you need to compile your functions into object code and provide the object file (either as a static archive or shared library) along with the header file. Whoever wants to use your function will then link his/her program to your objecet file/shared lib. This way, you can keep your source code implementation to yourself. Your header file would be:

```
#ifndef __SOME_MACRO_TO_PREVENT_MULTIPLE_INCLUSION__
#define __SOME_MACRO_TO_PREVENT_MULTIPLE_INCLUSION__

    int find_determinant();


#endif
```

Beware of multiple inclusion problems (I have shown above how to avoid this so that if your matrix.h file is included several times, programs will still compile).